# Adverb form of novel?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

It looks like 'novelistically' and 'novelly' are both correct. I'm sure there must be some subtleties in their usage. Can someone please suggest when to use which form?

Comment: More than subtleties; they have different meanings, one from the noun (a work of fiction) and one from the adjective (new). Did your dictionary not tell you this?

Comment: @Kate Sorry, I has just done a Google search, and carelessly perhaps. My bad...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you're mixing up two things here: There's the adjective "novel", which has a similar meaning to "new". On the other hand, there's the noun "novel", which means [a type of narrative fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novel). In connection to the noun "novel", there's the adjective "novelistical".

"novelly" is the adverb form of the adjective "novel". "novelistically" is the adverb form of the adjective "novelistical".

> He wrote his speech novelly. -> He wrote his speech in a new / novel way.

> He wrote his speech novelistically. -> He wrote his speed in a way somehow connected to a novel.

But in my experience, neither "novelly" nor "novelistically" is very common in every day use. I don't remember running across them in the last few decades ;)

Comment: No, I had to check that _novelly_ was indeed a real word.